# How to make a variable "Counter" count the number of "div's" that are created randomly and disappeared by click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am supposed to generate random number of "div" and when I click on the "div" , the "div" I clicked on must disappear by using "fadeout" .
The number of "div's" displayed and lost as a result of the click will be counted with a counter that will be shown in the upper right corner of the page.

The following code generates random number of "div" but I do not know how to make the "div" disappear and how to count the "div" that disappeared.

I have tried this

```
  $("div").click(function()
  {
     $("div").fadeOut() ;
  });
```

But when I click on arbitrary "div" all the "div" in the  page also disappear. I do not want all the "div's" to disappear at once .I want only the "div" that I have  clicked on to disappear and to be calculated.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <style>
        #Counter 
        {
         position: fixed ;
         top: 0 ;
         right: 0 ;
         width: 300px ;
         border: 3px solid grey ;
         background-color: lightpink ;
        }
        </style>

    </head>        

<body onload = "followMouse();">


 <div id = "Counter">Counter:</div>

 <script>

 $(document).ready(function()
 {  
  var Min_Width, Max_Width, Min_height, Max_height ;

  Min_Width = prompt("Please give the minimum width of div", "0") ;
  Max_Width = prompt("Please give the maximum width of div" , "700") ;
  Min_height = prompt("Please give the minimum height of div" , "0") ;
  Max_height = prompt("Please give the maximum height of div" , "500") ;

 function Random_Generator(Lower, Upper) 
 {
  var Random_Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Upper - Lower + 1) ) ; 
  return Random_Number ;
 }

 function Div_Generator()
 {
  var dfrag = document.createDocumentFragment() ;
  var count = Random_Generator(3, 200) ;
  var Counter = 0 ;

  for (var Counter = 0; Counter < count; Counter++)
  {
    var div = document.createElement("div") ;

    dfrag.appendChild(div) ;
  }

  for (Counter = 0; Counter < dfrag.childNodes.length; Counter++) 
  {
    div = dfrag.childNodes[Counter] ;

    alterDivStyle(div) ;
  }

  document.body.appendChild(dfrag) ;
 }

 function rndColor() 
 {
   var r = ('0' + Random_Generator(0,255).toString(16)).substr(-1), 
   g = ('0' + Random_Generator(0,255).toString(16)).substr(-1), 
   b = ('0' + Random_Generator(0,255).toString(16)).substr(-1) ;
   return '#' + r + g + b ;
 }

 function alterDivStyle(div)
 {

  div.style.width = Random_Generator(Min_Width, Max_Width) + "px" ; 

  div.style.height = Random_Generator(Min_height, Max_height) + "px" ;

  div.style.backgroundColor = rndColor() ;

  div.style.color = rndColor() ;

  div.style.position = "static" ;

  div.style.float = "right" ;

  div.style.border = '1px' ;

  div.style.border = "solid";

  div.style.borderColor = rndColor();

  div.style.borderWidth = rndColor();
 }

 Div_Generator() ;
 $("div").click(function()
 {
    $("div").fadeOut() ;
 });

}) ;

 </script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `$(this).fadeOut()` to get the target div on click
- Use `:visible` and `:hidden` selector to select the visible and hidden divs
- Get the count of visible/hidden divs in the `fadeOut()` callback function to get the count after effect finished

---

```
 $("div").click(function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(function(){
        console.log($('div:hidden').length);
     }) ;
  });
```

> **Additional** With dynamic generated divs you'll need to use `$(document).on('click' , 'div' , function(){` instead of
>   `$("div").click(function(){`

Comment: If you call `$("div").click` every time after you created the div's it works too but `$(document).on(....)` seems to be best practice.

Answer (score 0):

in order to make sure that only you count the `div`s that are supposed to count, give them a class or a data like:

```
$('<div class="clickable" />").appendTo($("body"));
```

And later on `fadeOut` get their length

```
 $(".clickable").click(
    function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(function(){
        console.log($('.clickable').length);
     }) ;
 });
```